# getimagesize() not working for remote URL's

Tags: php

When I deploy my code on server it does not work. It says "wap.example.com didn’t send any data.". Commenting the `getimagesize` function makes the page work.

I tried `getimagesize` with local images on server it works fine.  While for remote URLs its not working. And enabling display errors, error reporting nothing gives any clue for the reason and not getting anything in error logs.

Basis on google and other forums

`allow_url_fopen` is enabled
`safe_mode` in php is not enabled
apache `mod_security` is not enabled

While `file_get_contents()` works fine for same image URL.

Comment: You need to `file_get_contents()` the image URL

Comment: Check the name of the file. If it has spaces, you must encode them. Notice also on local web server using Windows, Test.GIF = TEST.GIF as on Unix server the 2 are differents. So be sure you use the correct name. (and show the piece of code you're using with the name)